# How do you send files (html, js, css and resources) when using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, socket.io

I am trying to create a web app that has the server updating the html material on the browser page in time intervals- a html slideshow.

I have a file structure that follows:

project:

- node_modules 
- app.js 
- index.html
- package.json 
- slides 
-- slide_0 
-- page.html 
--- images 
---- some .jpg files 
--- js 
---- script.js 
--- styles 
---- style.css 
-- slide_X ... etc.

What I have now is the possibility to send a string representation to the client using `fs.readFile(__dirname + "slides/slide_0/page.html")` and in the callback save the string and emit at `socket.on('connection')`.

The goal is to have a `div` in the index.html / client where I can append all the code in the page.html (i.e. the page.html does not need to be fully formated, a `<p> Hello World </p>` would suffice). Also, I would like the page.html to be able to have its own `.js`, `.css` and resources (as seen in the file structure above).

It is possible to have the imports (`link src="..."` and `script src="..."`) in the html and I can append it to the div, it's just a string. But, I don't know how to use the asset-files (`.js`, `.css` and the `.jpg`s).

I am using Express but I am not very good at it, just like socket.io.

- So, how can I send the files necessary to the client?
- What means to I use to send the html+files?
- Would some other structure be better? Fully formated HTML for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and a large bug which made it hard to work.

So, it is possible for me to `.empty()` the div with jquery and then append the read html file as string representation. When debugging I found that the `GET`s the browser were trying to do was incorrect and that was the entire error.

At the moment I have an express get-handling that accept all GETs. But, in the page.html I used srcs and refs that was relative to their filestructure- this has to be modified so that it starts in node-server-base, not html-file-structure-base.

So, It's no problem with sending code (in string format) with `socket.io` and appending it to the existing HTML. Just make sure the server is allowing access to the sourced files and that the urls is correct!